# Which of following is non pre-emptive OS?

Tags: operating-system, preemptive

Which of the following is non pre-emptive OS?

a)  DOS
b)  UNIX
c)  LINUX
d)  WINDOWS 2003

Comment: Voting to close because not about programming, possible homework and a simple thing to find out using a few second on the web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DOS is not a pre-emptive operating system, while Unix, Linux and versions of Windows from 1995 onwards are pre-emptive.